# Custom map navigation (turn by turn) in ios

Tags: ios, routes, mkmapview

I want to implement navigation map for drivers in my iOS app and know two different ways to do this:

```
Use URL scheme to open Apple Maps app.
Implement this feature inside my app.
```

The first case is not an option for me, so I decide to select a second. As I can see from Apple documentation, there are no such standard API. For now I can receive array of routes between source and destination points via MKDirectionsResponse object; also I can draw some route on my map. So the next step is to provide turn-by-turn navigation from source point to destination point according to the route and some following requirements:

```
Displaying next turns.
The navigation should be voice-guided.
The navigation should be on a 3d map.
The map should rotate in the direction of driving as you drive.
Should display ETA to final destination (the end point).
```

I thinks that all this features (may be, except item 2) can be reached by the way of using location and map services provided by CoreLocation and MapKit frameworks. But I'm ready to use third-party free / paid services. All that I found:

```
atlasct
navigenie
cloudmade
```

I can't find some references to source codes / SDK's (even limited demo if they are paid) for items 1 and 3. Item 2 also doesn't offer some demo SDK so I can't learn and evaluate Navigenie services quality.

So my question: does you know some third-party libs / frameworks / SDK's that can help me to resolve my problem? Does you know any solution to voice-guided navigation? Know you smth about wroted above instruments or may be you think that I must implement all features from the beggining?

Thanks!

Comment: in route i want to arrow, sound everything same as Apple maps

Comment: Not possible I think. Another similar discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555198/getting-routes-and-turn-by-turn-navigation-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: hello Dima, is it any Apple Document available for that?

Comment: r u got any solution?? @bhaveshvirani63